# How to redesign the product page in the wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have tried to redesign a WordPress theme product page designed for woocommerce.
it can not be edited with elementor page builder. and I want to add an elementor element to the product page.
I'd be thankful if you can help. cause I'm not good with WordPress and its themes.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit using elementor plugin and here is the step by step guide available
https://elementor.com/blog/customize-woocommerce-product-page/